# WebApi with string parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

My webapi method couldn't accept string parameter.

In post method in webapi controller , i could get only an optional string parameter, but when i test my method without parameter it get following error:

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)' .

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult List(string munZone="")
{ 

}
in route config:
          routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi3",
        url: "api/{controller}/{action}"
      );
            routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi2",
    url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

I need to send nullable string parameter instead of int id parameter

Comment: Show request url working &  nonworking and why you are use List as action name ,use something  else apart from keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it,if i send param as object of class, this problem will resolve.

> public class T{
>   public string munZone
>   }
>
> [HttpPost]
>   public IHttpActionResult List(T t)
>   {
>
> }